# What features in Azure services cannot be scripted in Terraform or require embedding ARM in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

When working with Terraform, what features of Azure services are there that cannot be scripted in Terraform or require embedding ARM?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no resource to create **Data Sync Group** in Azure using Terraform

An ARM template configures the Azure PaaS resources to send their diagnostic data to Log Analytics. There is no functionality for this in Terraform when used with Azure

There is a zone to zone disaster recovery for Azure VM but terraform only provides single instance and target availability set in the azure site recovery

Almost all the new features added in Azure cannot be created using Terraform

Comment: Thanks. How do you find out it is not supported in Terraform? Is there a webpage or similar to check?

Comment: These are the few things I tested out earlier. I am not sure if any documentation is there to check which services terraform does not support.

Comment: By "new features", what is the definition? in time (GA in the past month?) or something else(e.g. preview?)? An example would be great., Thanks.

Comment: Please upvote the post if you think it would be helpful to others.

Comment: You can refer https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14193

Answer (score 1):

The landscape for both Azure and Terraform is constantly changing, so it would not make much sense to list what is supported/not supported in a Stack Overflow context.

I have been working with Terraform in Azure for more than 5 years, and the AzureRM provider is being updated almost on a biweekly basis. In general, it is very much up to date - not only with new resources and data sources that are being added constantly but also updates on existing components functionality and when the Azure API changes. This provider rocks!

Take a look at the changelog here to get an overview of the intense activity on the AzureRM provider: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

I believe that instead of asking what is not supported, take a look at the landscape you want to create, and see if the components exist in the documentation, which is very good IMO. I think that the latest AzureRM provider (2.91.0) has around 950+ resources and data sources.

Documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs

Usually, when something does not exist there will be an issue in the Github repo. E.g. to follow the example that @RamaroAdapa-MT mentions, you can find the issue here (by a simple Google search):
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6425

Looking through that, you can see the the reason is actually not a Terraform AzureRM provider issue, but lack of support in the Azure API:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/11061

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Both answers can be marked as answers. One side question, I wonder if you could recommend learning resources for learning Terraform with Azure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start reading the Azure docs on the component(s) you want to create and understand what is needed in your scenario. Then look at the Terraform component(s) and see if you can map the properties up. Sometimes it is not so obvious as you might need to use several TF resources obtain the functionality. If you are in doubt, spin up the resource with Terraform and take a look in the Azure portal. If there are settings in the portal that aren't as expected, change it in the portal and then run a new tf plan to see if tf detects the change. Now you have identified the property you need to set/change.

Comment: Two things that are important: 1. Use the Azure remote backend for your state storage. 2. Learn and understand the difference between Terraforms count and for_each iterators. Hint: use for_each for data critical components. (E.g. databases) to avoid reprovisioning of e.g. databases when requirements changes.

Comment: Thanks. We only have Read permission on Azure portal. Does it mean it is more difficult for us to detect the change required to apply to TF?